What should be the output of lsb_release -a?
I recently upgraded (via notification) Ubuntu Studio from 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS, and I have noticed that many packages that I used to have installed, and that I believe are supposed to be part of the Ubuntu Studio distribution seem to be missing [1]. I think that I have some other strange behaviour too, such as that the output of lsb_release -a is:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble

I'm fairly certain that this used to report "Ubuntu Studio" instead of "Ubuntu". Am I misremembering?
[1] E.g. Studio Controls is not installed, and PulseAudio seems to be installed now instead of PipeWire.

You are misremembering.

Your base system is Ubuntu regardless of what flavor you're using... The system I'm using now was made during flavor media, and lsb_release will always report Ubuntu, but neofetch can report my system as Lubuntu, Xubuntu, or Ubuntu depending on how it is run and what I'm using at the time (FYI:  I have xubuntu-desktop, lubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-desktop & more installed.. but even if I didn't have ubuntu-desktop it'll still report as Ubuntu when using root or sudo as the flavor detail is hidden

Ah, neofetch of course! Now I "just" need to work out what's missing and re-add it...

I'm using my primary box and logged into a Lubuntu session (ie. LXQt desktop from the Lubuntu team)
If I run lsb_release on my system it'll report as follows
guiverc@d7050-next:~/uwn/issues/860$   lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.10
Release:        24.10
Codename:       oracular

However if I use neofetch instead, and I'm not elevating privileges with sudo it'll report I'm using Lubuntu.
guiverc@d7050-next:~/uwn/issues/860$   neofetch 
           `-mddhhhhhhhhhddmss`
        ./mdhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.                                                                                                                    
     :mdhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhm`                                                                                                                  
   :ymhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhyyyyyyhhhhhhhhhy:                                                                                                                 
  `odhyyyhhhhhhhhhy+-````./syhhhhhhhho`                                                                                                                
 `hhy..:oyhhhhhhhy-`:osso/..:/++oosyyyh`    guiverc@d7050-next                                                                                         
 dhhs   .-/syhhhhs`shhhhhhyyyyyyyyyyyyhs    ------------------                                                                                         
:hhhy`  yso/:+syhy/yhhhhhshhhhhhhhhhhhhh:   OS: Lubuntu 24.10 x86_64                                                                                   
hhhhho. +hhhys++oyyyhhhhh-yhhhhhhhhhhhhhs   Host: OptiPlex 7050                                                                                        
hhhhhhs-`/syhhhhyssyyhhhh:-yhhhhhhhhhhhhh   Kernel: 6.11.0-8-generic                                                                                   
hhhhhhs  `:/+ossyyhyyhhhhs -yhhhhhhhhhhhh   Uptime: 3 days, 4 mins                                                                                     
hhhhhhy/ `syyyssyyyyhhhhhh: :yhhhhhhhhhhs   Packages: 3890 (dpkg), 28 (snap)                                                                           
:hhhhhhyo:-/osyhhhhhhhhhhho  ohhhhhhhhhh:   Shell: bash 5.2.32                                                                                         
 sdhhhhhhhyyssyyhhhhhhhhhhh+  +hhhhhhhhs    Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080, 1920x1080, 1280x1024                                                     
 `shhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhy+` .yhhhhhhhh`    DE: LXQt 2.0.0                                                                                             
  +sdhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhyo/. `/yhhhhhhhd`     WM: Xfwm4                                                                                                  
   `:shhhhhhhhhh+---..``.:+yyhhhhhhh:       WM Theme: Pills                                                                                            
     `:mdhhhhhh/.syssyyyyhhhhhhhd:`         Theme: Greybird [GTK2/3]                                                                                   
        `+smdhhh+shhhhhhhhhhhhdm`           Icons: oxygen [GTK2/3]                                                                                     
           `sNmdddhhhhhhhddm-`              Terminal: qterminal                                                                                        
                                            Terminal Font: IBM Plex Mono Text 14 
                                            CPU: Intel i5-6500 (4) @ 3.600GHz 
                                            GPU: Intel HD Graphics 530 
                                            GPU: AMD ATI Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series 
                                            Memory: 8488MiB / 15338MiB 

Also note if I run sudo neofetch whilst in this Lubuntu session, the system won't detect the Lubuntu/LXQt and will just report my system as Ubuntu, as it's getting some details from the root user and not my actual user.
guiverc@d7050-next:~/uwn/issues/860$   sudo neofetch 
[sudo] password for guiverc: 
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`                                                                                                                       
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-                                                                                                                     
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.                                                                                                                   
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/                                                                                                                  
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     root@d7050-next                                                                                             
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    ---------------                                                                                             
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   OS: Ubuntu 24.10 x86_64                                                                                     
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Host: OptiPlex 7050                                                                                         
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   Kernel: 6.11.0-8-generic                                                                                    
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   Uptime: 3 days, 8 mins                                                                                      
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Packages: 3890 (dpkg), 28 (snap)                                                                            
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.2.32                                                                                          
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080, 1920x1080, 1280x1024                                                      
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     DE: LXQt 2.0.0                                                                                              
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      WM: Xfwm4                                                                                                   
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Theme: Arc-Darker [GTK3]                                                                                    
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Icons: elementary-xfce-dark [GTK3]                                                                          
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           Terminal: qterminal                                                                                         
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               CPU: Intel i5-6500 (4) @ 3.600GHz                                                                           
                                           GPU: Intel HD Graphics 530 
                                           GPU: AMD ATI Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series 
                                           Memory: 8562MiB / 15338MiB 
                                                                                                                   
                                                                

My system is actually a multi-desktop install; so if I elect to login with a Xubuntu session, lsb_release will still report the system as Ubuntu as that is what my system is, but neofetch will report the system as Xubuntu as that is the desktop (Xfce) I'm using.  If I login with the Ubuntu Desktop session, I'll be using GNOME and there both neofetch and lsb_release will report my system as Ubuntu.
I won't logout and switch sessions to show it'll report as Xubuntu etc; sorry I'm too lazy.
If interested in my install media; I actually used Xubuntu media on this install, but neither lsb_release or neofetch worry about that.
guiverc@d7050-next:~/uwn/issues/860$   cat /var/log/installer/media-info 
Xubuntu 23.10 "Mantic Minotaur" - Daily amd64 (20230829)

